# Apache solr returns error as Could not load config for solrconfig.xml

Tags: apache, solr

I followed [this](http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2009/05/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql-db/) tutorial for solr searching.

I did all 5 steps in that tutorial. But after that I loaded the solr as:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin` then I got this error.

```
Problem accessing /solr/admin. Reason:

    {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:860)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:251)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:120)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:589)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanComment(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanComment(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:134)
    ... 14 more
,code=500}
```

**UPDATE**

REplaced the solrconfig.xml with new file...then i go tthis error:

HTTP ERROR 500

```
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unknown fieldType 'text' specified on field firstname,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unknown fieldType 'text' specified on field firstname
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:860)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:251)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldType 'text' specified on field firstname
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.loadFields(IndexSchema.java:644)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:470)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:619)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
,code=500}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably by mistake inserted ' ' before > and have  something like that

```
-- >
```

Please download latest 4.4 from site, unzip and replace solrconfig.xml.

example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml

I've done this yesterday and I haven't got any error. 
Last stack contains an answer for you

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

If you don't see a mistake open solrconfig.xml in eclipse (or similar ide) this should help

Comment: i removed the solrconfig.xml with new one ...then i got the error thats in `UPDATE` section....

Comment: can you  give me the steps you did for that, or put a link for reference..........

Comment: Did you add this firstname field into solrcondig.xml ? Just replace all configuration. Backup old one. I don't see any field firstname in example

Comment: iam new in this , so ver tought to follow the instruction to search

Comment: the solar folder downloade from `http://lucene.apache.org/solr/` this url, and when try to follow the steps 1 to 5 from this url `http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2009/05/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql-db/` , then it will became error....

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is ancient. It appears to be for Solr 1.3. Instead, use the official Solr tutorial: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html